# Prove that if $a^n-1$ is prime, then $a=2$ and $n$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $a^n-1$ is prime, then $a=2$ and $n$ is prime.

I just started a semester with Number Theory, and I don't know how I am expected to be dealing with such questions. I am really frustrated. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: And $n \geq 2$.Take $n=1$ and $a=8$ for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:$a^n-1= (a-1)(a^{n-1}+\cdots+a+1)$.

Comment: Thank you for you hint!
Any suggestion as for how to arrive at $a=2$ or $n$ is prime?
Should I start with $a=2$?

Comment: Plug in a few numbers,including $a=2$ and see what happens.

Comment: @Meitar Hint: try to take $a\to a^m$ in the formula above

Comment: Oh, do you mean that with the form you brought it to, I can see that $a^n-1$ is divisible not only by itself and by 1?

Comment: No, if both factors are $>1$, then $a$ is composite.

Comment: How is it contradictory to what I asked?

Comment: Oh. I misread it. Sorry.