# Show that if $n>1$ and $a$ is a positive integer with $a^n-1$ prime, then $a=2$ and $n$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Show that if $n>1$ and $a$ is a positive integer with $a^n-1$ prime, then $a=2$ and $n$ is prime.
>
> *Hint:* Look at the proposition, if $n$ is composite then $2^n-1$ is composite.

Comment: What have you done? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry to answer -- should have looked for a duplicate first.

Comment: More duplicates: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559994/prime-numbers-of-form-an-1), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189742/prove-that-if-an-1-is-prime-then-a-2-and-n-is-prime), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927678/foundational-proof-for-mersenne-primes).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Firstly, we have:
$$
a^n - 1 = (a-1)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \cdots + a^2 + a + 1)
$$
Secondly, if $n$ is not prime, say $n = ij$ with $i, j \ge 2$, then we have (by the same factorization trick):
$$
a^n - 1 = a^{ij} - 1 = (a^i - 1)(a^{ij - i} + a^{ij-2i} + \cdots + a^{2i} + a^i + 1).
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $m$ divides $n$ and $1<m<n$, then $a^m-1>1$ also divides $a^n-1$. So $n$ must be prime.